# Lucene PorterStemming

Tags: java, eclipse, lucene

I am looking for some help in lucene 7 with the use of porter stemming. I cant find anything in the way of allowing me to pass a stemmer into my writer. I am fairly new to this so there might be a way to do this by tolkenising but i was hoping to do it all in one as i have alot of files to be stemmed.

```
public void indexWithUrls(String rootpath) throws IOException {
    try {
        Directory index = FSDirectory.open(INDEX_DIR2);

        EnglishAnalyzer an = new EnglishAnalyzer();
        IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(an);
        // our created analyser
        config.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE);
        writer = new IndexWriter(index, config);
        File f = new File(rootpath);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, you are already using porter stemming.

You would incorporate the stemmer into your analyzer. See the [Analyzer documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/7_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer.html) for an example of how to create the analysis chain in a custom analyzer. You would add stemming as one of the filters in the analyzer.

EnglishAnalyzer already has stemming built in, using a [PorterStemFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/7_1_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/en/PorterStemFilter.html).

Comment: Thanks for the input, it cleared up the problem and the links were very helpful. Thanks again !